# Database stuck in restoring state

Tags: database, sql-server-2008-r2, database-restore, repair

Last night I had a database that had it's data and log files physically removed without first taking the proper steps to move the database files.

After the disk were physically reattached, the database went into "Restoring..." state.

I have tried the most recommended steps for this situation, including restoring with recovery, dropping the database, detaching the database, and taking the database offline. If I try to drop or delete the database, SSMS tells me that the command was successful, but when I refresh the connection, the database appears back in the db list with the state of *Restoring...*

I'm wondering if there are any other methods of repairing the database or even just removing it, without taking the server or service offline.

**Edit:**

The errors look like this:

> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 RESTORE DATABASE is terminating
>   abnormally. Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 RESTORE DATABASE is
>   terminating abnormally. Msg 823, Level 24, State 2, Line 1 The
>   operating system returned error 64(The specified network name is no
>   longer available.) to SQL Server during a read at offset
>   0x00000000012000 in file '****'. Additional messages in the SQL Server
>   error log and system event log may provide more detail. This is a
>   severe system-level error condition that threatens database integrity
>   and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database
>   consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many
>   factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.

Answer (score 2):

I had experienced a worse scenario and I had written up a guide which might help you out, I guess you can start on the part where I started restoring the database.  Here is it
http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/08/24/reparing-suspect-sql-database/